# Flutter List<int> LITTLE ENDIAN Order?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am converting Java code to Dart, but I am stuck in Little Endian oder, Any ideas to help me?

Java:

```
void displayString(byte[] record) {
   ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(record);
   bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
   .....
}
```

Dart:

```
_displayString(List<int> record) {
 var _list = Uint8List.fromList(record);
// HOW TO ORDER LITTLE ENDIAN Like Java
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent to Java Byte buffer is Dart's ByteData.

```
var byteData = _list.buffer.asByteData();
```

You can't set its order globally, but you can specify it for each get or set.

```
byteData.setFloat32(0, 3.04, Endian.little);
```

Comment: byteData.setFloat32(0, 3.04, Endian.little);

you mean 0 is the index of list record, right?

Comment: the float represented by the 4 bytes starting at the 0th byte - so bytes 0, 1, 2 and 3. The next entity would therefore start at byte 4. Also note that ByteData doesn't have the concept of a current position like ByteBuffer, so you always need to specify this offset.